# Increment loop counter in Jekyll

Tags: html, templates, jekyll, liquid

So I'm trying to create a page where only the first 10 posts are shown, at start.

Done like this, its simple enough :

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
    <li>//show post</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But then it gets tricky because I want to add a button that make visible the next 10 posts. Then another one for the next 10 posts, until every post on the site is shown.

Basically, all posts will be generated on the index because jekyll is static. But everything after the tenth post will be hidden with js and css. But still, I need to generate those posts ten by ten right ?

So I'm trying to do something like that

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 offset:9%}
     //show post
{% endfor %}

{% for post in site.posts limit:10 offset:19%}
     //show post
{% endfor %}
```

Its still bad because I have to write my loop for every ten posts, so its very bad. So basically I have to create a loop that create my UL 10 posts per 10 posts. What it comes down to is, how can I add ten to the offset everytime ? I have to use a variable but I'm not sure how the syntax works here ?

Here is my desired html render :

```
<div id="first-ten"> 
    // ten posts
</div>

<div id="see-more-1">
    // ten posts
</div>

<div id="see-more-2">
    // ten posts
</div>

<div id="see-more-3">
    // last six posts for instance
</div>
```

Comment: Strange idea. You will load everything, hide post and force your users to click to read already loaded content ? What's the benefits ?

Comment: Why not? Its just posts excerpts, it wont take a lot of space on load. The benefits are the user can continue reading posts excerpts without changing page, and without having a very long vertical page to read. Think how instagram works, but with a static architecture

Comment: @topleft : load all excerpts once in a list, each one in its own list-item, and hide them from the 11th element via CSS. Thus show them ten by ten via javascript

Comment: well that's not a bad idea actually, I might do that. I also thought I could use jekyll paginator to create different html pages containing my posts, then call the html pages via ajax. This has the benefit to load a lighter index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that using Liquid is a strange way of doing this, but just to show that it can be done:

```
---
---
{% comment %}Constant, can assign in _config.yml or YAML front matter if desired{% endcomment %}
{% assign postsPerPage = 2 %}

{% assign numPages = site.posts | size | divided_by: postsPerPage %}
{% comment %}Sketchy ceiling function since Liquid does integer division{% endcomment %}
{% if site.posts.size | modulo: postsPerPage > 0 %}
    {% assign numPages = numPages | plus: 1 %}
{% endif %}
Total pages: {{ numPages }}<br><br>
{% assign endIndex = numPages | minus: 1 %}

{% comment %}Output section{% endcomment %}
{% for pageNum in (0..endIndex) %}
  {% assign offset = pageNum | times: postsPerPage %}
  <div id="see-more-{{ pageNum }}" style="border-style: inset;">
  Page {{ pageNum }}:<br>
      <ol>
      {% assign posts = site.posts | sort: 'title' %}
      {% for post in posts limit: postsPerPage offset: offset %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ol>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tested the above page with anywhere from 1-11 posts. I tried to write it as self-explanatory as possible, so there may ways to reduce the amount of variables/calculations.